# How to customize popup windows on Leaflet markers like this?

Tags: leaflet, markers

I am actually looking for a way to customize my window popups like it is done on this website : http://www.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/quiet/#/map/
I have been looking on all the web and no way to find it ...

Any ideas or website explaining it ?
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code uses a combination of [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/), [qTip2](http://qtip2.com/), and a couple of other libraries for localization and media player abilities.

You can find the specific javascript code for those markers here: [NYTimes Map - zoom.js](http://graphics8.nytimes.com/packages/js/newsgraphics/lib/maps/zoom.js)

All the css is found here: [NYTimes Map - quiet.css](http://graphics8.nytimes.com/packages/css/multimedia/bundles/projects/2013/Quiet.css)

The main tool used for the mouseover parts is qTip2.  [Tutorials](http://qtip2.com/guides) and [demos](http://qtip2.com/demos) can be found on the website.  That's probably the thing you're going to want to start with.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Leaflet extention called [Leaflet.Rrose](http://erictheise.github.io/rrose/). Description from [Leaflet plugins page](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html):

> For use when you want popups on mouseover, not click, and you need popup tips to reorient as you get close to the edges of your map.

Check out examples on extensions' page.